# Problem of graphic performance, "glxgears" between different users

Tags: root, nvidia, graphics, graphic-card

I have a problem of performance with 3D Graphic NVIDIA (Quadro FX GRID K2/PCIe/SSE2), when I run `glxgears` in a terminal as root, the system performance is 9676 FPS, but if I run `glxgears` with other user, the performance is 0.062 FPS.

Comment: You can test to see if its an environment problem with sudo -E, which gives you root, but preserves the user's environment variables.

Comment: First, `glxgears` is not a benchmark. Second, what are your permissions on `/dev/nvidia*`? Have you set custom `NVreg_*` parameters?

Comment: @cohensh Its not an environment problem;
The issue is weird, I note something new, so the question should change, the problem sometimes occurs with the user root, sometimes with other user, and vice versa, the issues sometimes reboot the machine.

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs after reinstall driver of NVIDIA, with the command sanity (Perform basic sanity tests on an existing NVIDIA driver Installation),  *nvidia-installer –sanity* , I could find the problem, (Error: The installed file *** has a different checksum (###) than when it was installed (###))
To fix it, delete manually these files and reinstall the driver.